# How does Apache solr Index different files

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I studied Apache lucene and found that until we store the fields using either field.store.Yes or store field, we cannot retrieve the particular field for the current hit.

Now in Apache solr we only use the following command to post the data for indexing

java -Durl=http://"localhost":8080/solr/update -jar post.jar *.xml

Now my question was does solr parse each filed in the xml file and store it or does it simple index the entire file without storing.

After searching a bit i got to know about schema.xml which specifies whether to store the fields or not.

Now i want know how to do the same for a **desktop application** so that i do not need to specify the store.filed.yes for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to the answer provided by @bmargulies, for a desktop application, you could either use [EmbeddedSolr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr) or manage your the index directly using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org). Between the two, I would recommend EmbeddedSolr as Solr is a best practice implementation of Lucene.

Comment: Do i still have to convert the text files into xml format. My text files are apache lucene log files having very large size's of about 4 to 5GB. My requirement is to parse these files using solr so that whenever I enter query string solr must return the entire line containing the query string. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Please see the updated answer to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496255/how-to-index-text-files-using-apache-solr

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends entirely on the contents of your Solr schema.xml. Solr will only store for fields defined in that file, and the field definitions in that file specify the Lucene parameters you reference. If a field is not called out in a `<field/>` or `<dynamicField/>` element, Solr logs an error; it won't store it or index it at all. So, you must allow for all your fields in your schema.

Solr can also, in its other configuration files, define 'update request processors' to perform additional pre-processing of the data.

Comment: The problem is solr is web application. My requirement is a desktop application. Is there a any app available like solr for desktop applications.